# how to draw open ended circle in open gl es android

Tags: android, opengl-es

I need to draw a open ended circle as shown in image attached below
http://i49.tinypic.com/254y5bs.png
In the image the length of M should be greater than N, and the starting points of lines M and N are the center of circle. How can I draw an arc from the end point of N to M such that the arc looks linear in shape.
 i am drawing the circle using the following code

```
    for (int nR = N_IN_DEGREE; nR < M_IN_DEGREE && nCount < 360; nR++) 
    { 
    float fX = (float) Math.sin((float) nR * (Math.PI / 180)) + nR * 0.0008f; 
    float fY = (float) Math.cos((float) nR * (Math.PI / 180)); 
    stVertexArray[nCount * 2] = fX; 
    stVertexArray[nCount * 2 + 1] = fY; 
    nCount++;
    }
```

I get the open end circle from the angles N_IN_DEGREE to M_IN_DEGREE..but as I am increasing the value of fX by a factor of nR * 0.0008f , the complete circle is drawn only with 350 degrees,but i want 360..please run the code and see..my requirement is that I need to draw 2 lines n(length 0.8) and line m(length=1) from a single point and draw a arc from end point of n to end point of m and fill the arc with a color as well..

Comment: If M is greater than N, it wouldn't be a circle, right? If you are trying to draw an ellipse, you can draw it using the GL_LINE primitive. An arc cant be "linear", but if you mean smooth, you just need more points on the curve. I think you should rephrase your entire question.

Comment: i am drawing the circle using the following code

Comment: @M-V i am drawing the circle using the following code  for (int nR = N_IN_DEGREE; nR < M_IN_DEGREE && nCount < 360; nR++) {

   float fX = (float) Math.sin((float) nR * (Math.PI / 180)) + nR * 0.0008f;
   float fY = (float) Math.cos((float) nR * (Math.PI / 180));

   stVertexArray[nCount * 2] = fX;
   stVertexArray[nCount * 2 + 1] = fY;
   nCount++;

  }   I get the open end circle from the angles N_IN_DEGREE to M_IN_DEGREE..but as I am increasing the value of fX by a factor of nR * 0.0008f , the complete circle is drawn only with  350 degrees,but i want 360..please run the code and see

Comment: You should edit your question to add the code. It's unreadable in the comment.

Comment: @M-V i am drawing the circle using the following code    for (int nR = N_IN_DEGREE; nR < M_IN_DEGREE && nCount < 360; nR++)     { float fX = (float) Math.sin((float) nR * (Math.PI / 180)) + nR * 0.0008f;     float fY = (float) Math.cos((float) nR * (Math.PI / 180));    stVertexArray[nCount * 2] = fX;    stVertexArray[nCount * 2 + 1] = fY; nCount++; } I get the open end circle from the angles N_IN_DEGREE to M_IN_DEGREE..but as I am increasing the value of fX by a factor of nR * 0.0008f , the complete circle is drawn only with 350 degrees,but i want 360..please run the code and see

Comment: @M-V i just cant get the code formatting to work..pls help

Comment: You are adding it to the comments section. Don't do that - please edit your *question* - that has all the formatting goodies.

Comment: @M-V edited the question..pls check..

Comment: @M-V can you please help me through this error..i updated the question now

Comment: Did you see my answer below? Please comment/vote if you found the answer useful.

Answer (score 0):

I can't make your code run, as there is not enough information, and I have trouble following your code.

But here is the basic idea, implemented in python.

```
import math

def genc(r1, r2, t1, t2, n):
    dr = (r2 - r1)/n
    dt = (t2 - t1)/n
    x = []
    y = []
    for k in range(n):
        r = r1 + k*dr
        t = t1 + k*dt
        x.append(r*math.cos(t))
        y.append(r*math.sin(t))
    return [x, y]
```

This is the output (plotted using matplotlib)

```
In [43]: a = circ.genc(1.0, 0.8, math.pi/2, 2*math.pi, 60)

In [44]: plot(a[0], a[1],'ro')
Out[44]: [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0xb9285d0>]
```

[image]